# Synchronizing parent and child in an infinite loop

Tags: c, fork

My goal from the code is the following:
-Generate a random number between a given range
-Make user guess the number using the child process
-Make the parent tell the user if guess should be higher/lower
-If guess is correct give a signal for the child to exit.

Current code:

```
int main() {

int randomnumber = 1+ rand() % 51;
int guess;
pid_t pid=fork();
bool signal=false;

if(pid<0){
    printf("Fork failed");
}

if(pid==0){
printf("Enter your guess: \n");
}

while(1)
{

if(pid==0){
    if(signal==true)
        exit(0);
scanf("%d", &guess);
}

print("test1"); //put this for debugging purposes and only executed once instead of twice


    if(pid>0){
      print("test2"); //this doesn't execute so I can conclude that parent isn't executing for some reason
      wait(NULL);//before adding this parent used to execute and I got an infinite amount of prints which is normal, adding it made the parent not execute

    if(guess>randomnumber){
        printf("Guess should be lower");
    }

    if(guess<randomnumber){
        printf("Guess should be higher");
    }

    if(guess==randomnumber){
        printf("WIN");
        signal=true;
        break;
    }
}
}
return 1;
}
```

Any idea what I can do to synchronize both of them? Why doesn't the parent execute after adding the wait function, it should at least execute the parent before wait(NULL).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @ayrebelcoding! Can you please format your code to improve readability? Regarding your question, you need to employ IPC(inter-process communication) mechanisms for that, like fifos or shared memory. You can't expect your int variables to share state between parent and child processes out of the box.

Comment: @vtronko [`stdbool.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean) was added in C99. Yeah, it really has been two decades.

Comment: @vtronko thank you. I used #include<stdbool.h> and it worked fine, didn't know it wasn't considered c, I am sorry. 
Since there is no way to do that this way then I will use pipes as I have limited experience with them.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry, I stand corrected, then. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @ayrebelcoding if you included `stdbool.h` you did it right. It's part of the language standard and has been for a *long* time.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you. Can you please confirm/deny what vtronko said so I close this question.

Comment: His observation is exactly correct. Either your variables must be stored in shared memory and properly synchronized (real PITA), or setup some pipes and toss data back and forth serially between the parent and child processes.

Comment: Consider also using `srand()` to initialize the random seed, otherwise `rand()` will always produce the same sequence of numbers. See https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/rand-and-srand-in-ccpp/amp/

Answer (score 0):

As some some users remarked in comments this cannot be done unless I implement inter-process communication or a shared memory.